# How to write a pytest for testing a method which has a wrapper inside it in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytest, wrapper

I have a class with some methods. I want to test both public and private methods. One of my private function has a wrapper inside it with an argument.
My question is how to test that method?

my method is as below:

```
    ...
    def _conv_bn_activation(self,
                            filters,
                            name=None):
        """a Conv2D -> SyncBatchNormalization -> Activation block"""

        def wrapper(input_tensor):
            return self._conv2d_bn(
                filters,
                kernel_size=self.kernel_size_,
                activation=self.activation_,
                kernel_initializer=self.kernel_initializer_,
                padding='same',
                use_batchnorm=self.use_batch_norm_,
                name=name,
                kernel_regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer_
            )(input_tensor)

        return wrapper
```

my pytest code is look like this:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('filters', [256, 128])
    def test_conv2d_layer(self, filters):
        model = Unet()
        assert isinstance(model._conv_bn_activation(
            filters=filters, name= "conv2d_layer9"),
            tfk.Model), f'failed with number of filters: {filters}'
```

the error message is look like this:

```
E       AssertionError: failed with number of filters: 256
E       assert False
E        +  where False = isinstance(<function AutoDeeplabv3_plus._aspp_module.<locals>.layer at 0x7ff4d13a5550>, <class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>)
E        +    where <function AutoDeeplabv3_plus._aspp_module.<locals>.layer at 0x7ff4d13a5550> = <bound method AutoDeeplabv3_plus._aspp_module of <aimedic.models.deeplab.AutoDeeplabv3_plus object at 0x7ff457ffa340>>(filters=256)
E        +      where <bound method AutoDeeplabv3_plus._aspp_module of <aimedic.models.deeplab.AutoDeeplabv3_plus object at 0x7ff457ffa340>> = <aimedic.models.deeplab.AutoDeeplabv3_plus object at 0x7ff457ffa340>._aspp_module
E        +    and   <class 'keras.engine.training.Model'> = tfk.Model

test_deeplab.py:138: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2):

function `_conv_bn_activation` returns function `wrapper`, to execute it need to run it (). so for example
`model._conv_bn_activation(filters=filters, name= "conv2d_layer9")` return `function` and to execute it `model._conv_bn_activation(filters=filters, name= "conv2d_layer9")()` and it needs input parameter `input_tensor`

To simplify it, and detail this post, below is the working example:

```
#Code under test code_oops.py
class A:
    def __init__(self,pos):
        self.char_at_pos=pos
class MyWord(A):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__(pos)
        self.number_of_chars=0
    def _conv_bn_activation(self,pos):
        def wrapper(input_tensor):
            return input_tensor(self.char_at_pos)     
        return wrapper
```

to test this, refer to the comment against the code.

```
from code_oops import *
from pytest import mark

@mark.parametrize("filter",[10,20])
def test_is_instance_and_wrapper(filter):
    a = A('1')
    my_word = MyWord('10')
    #assert isinstance(my_word._conv_bn_activation(20),str),f'failed for {filter}' # not calling to execute i.e missing () of wrapper, so this is comparing function vs str
    assert isinstance(my_word._conv_bn_activation(20)(str),str),f'failed for {filter}' # Right way! called my_word._conv_bn_activation(20)(str) with (str)
```

so your code would be

```
assert isinstance(model._conv_bn_activation(
            filters=filters, name= "conv2d_layer9")(input_tensor),
            tfk.Model), f'failed with number of filters: {filters}'
```